# PackageManager$NameNotFoundException fo JNI project

Tags: android, android-ndk

Getting PackageManager$NameNotFoundException for the signature capturing code in android studio

```
package com.example.u29692.helloandroidjni;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.jni_msgView)).setText(stringFromJNI(this));
}
// new code
static {
    System.loadLibrary("hello-android-jni");
}
// public native String getMsgFromJni();
public native String stringFromJNI(Context context);
```

jni.c

```
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_u29692_helloandroidjni_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance,
                                                               jobject context) {

    // TODO

    // For class Context
    jclass native_clazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, context);

    // Get the getPackageManager method ID
    jmethodID methodID_func = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, native_clazz,
                                              "getPackageManager", "()Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;");

    // Access manager application package
    jobject package_manager = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, context, methodID_func);

    // For class PackageManager
    jclass pm_clazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, package_manager);

    // Get the getPackageInfo method ID
    jmethodID methodID_pm = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, pm_clazz,
                                            "getPackageInfo", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/content/pm/PackageInfo;");

    // To obtain the application package information
    jobject package_info = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, package_manager,
                                                methodID_pm, (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "com.example.u29692.helloandroidjni"), 64);
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, package_info);
}
```

Application is crashing with the logs:

```
10-14 12:12:55.038: A/art(17135): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewStringUTF called with pending exception 'android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException' thrown in unknown throw location
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
10-14 12:12:55.198: A/art(17135): sart/runtime/runtime.cc:292] Pending exception android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException thrown by 'unknown throw location'
0-14 12:12:55.198: A/art(17135): sart/runtime/runtime.cc:292] android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.example.u29692.helloandroidjni
10-14 12:12:55.198: A/art(17135): sart/runtime/runtime.cc:292]   at android.content.pm.PackageInfo android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(java.lang.String, int) (ApplicationPackageManager.java:167)
10-14 12:12:55.198: A/art(17135): sart/runtime/runtime.cc:292]   at java.lang.String
```

Comment: Is `com.example.u29692.helloandroidjni` the package name you've specified in your manifest?

Comment: yes manifest file:<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.u29692.helloandroidjni">